# How to improve performance in rendering image?

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I am drawing image on a custom `UIView`. On resizing the view, the drawing performance goes down and it starts lagging.

My image drawing code is below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIBezierPath *bpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    CGContextAddPath(context, bpath.CGPath);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, [self bounds], image.CGImage);
}
```

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better using Instruments to find where the bottleneck is than asking on here.

However, what you will probably find is that every time the frame changes slightly the entire view will be redrawn.

If you're just using the `drawRect` to clip the view into an oval (I guess there's an image behind it or something) then you would be better off using a `CAShapeLayer`.

Create a `CAShapeLayer` and give it a `CGPath` then add it as a clipping layer to the `view.layer`.

Then you can change the path on the `CAShapeLayer` and it will update. You'll find (I think) that it performs much better too.

Answer (score 0):

If your height and width are the same, you could just use a UIImageView instead of needing a custom view, and get the circular clipping by setting properties on the image view's layer.  That approach draws nice and quickly.

Just set up a UIImageView (called "image" in my example) and then have your view controller do this once:

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.size.width / 2.0;
image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks w0mbat, but in my case clipping path as well as image data varies. @Fogmeister answer fulfilled my requirement.